# Magento2 How I can add autocomplete field in order grid filter section

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add product Id field in filter section of sales order grid which is autocomplete. I have done with autocomplete but I fail to bind that new value to text-box. How we can bind custom value to filter text-box?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Have you got the solution?